# error Class cast exception in main

Tags: java, json, csv

I am trying to convert json file into csv file and I am using following code for that

```
    public File convert(File toConvert) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String JsonString = "{\"value\": [{\"name\",\"kind\":\"url\":]}";
            JSONParser file = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = file;


            JSONObject jsonfile = (JSONObject) obj;                 //JSONObject from map interface
            String name = (String) jsonfile.get("name");
            System.out.println(name);
            String kind = (String) jsonfile.get("kind");
            System.out.println(kind);
            JSONArray url = (JSONArray) jsonfile.get("url");        //JSONArray from list interface
            Iterator<String> iterator = url.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }


        return toConvert ;
}
```

and my json file has a huge data and it looks like this

> {
>     "value":[
>       {
>         "name":"accountleadscollection","kind":"EntitySet","url":"accountleadscollection"
>       },{
>         "name":"accounts","kind":"EntitySet","url":"accounts"
>       },{
>         "name":"activitymimeattachments","kind":"EntitySet","url":"activitymimeattachments"
>       },{
>         "name":"activityparties","kind":"EntitySet","url":"activityparties"
>       },{
>         "name":"activitypointers","kind":"EntitySet","url":"activitypointers"
>       },{
>         "name":"annotations","kind":"EntitySet","url":"annotations"
>       },{
>         "name":"annualfiscalcalendars","kind":"EntitySet","url":"annualfiscalcalendars"
>       },{...............

whenever I am trying to execute the code i am getting this error,`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException`. Is the logic I am following is correct or can anyone provide a better code for that, and I am implementing an interface which is having this method.

Comment: Why are you casting "url" to JsonArray ? In your example, it's a string.

Comment: url is just a string like a name but not an actual url

Comment: The fact that your method doesn't use its input parameter other than to return should give you cause for concern. You don't appear to be actually parsing anything. I think you should probably start again, and look at one thing at a time. Hint: casting `JSONParser` to `JSONObject` isn't the right start. Look at what methods `JSONParser` exposes...

Comment: If url is a string, why are you writing `JSONArray url = (JSONArray) jsonfile.get("url");` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the `String` in `JSONObject`.
2. Get the Array in the `JSONObject` by using the method `getJSONArray("arraName")`.
3. If the array consist of Object then Iterate the array and then get the object using the index using method `getJSONObject(index)`.
4. Now get the value using the key.

Here is the sample code in which you can do this.

**Parse JSON from the string:**

```
     public void convert() throws JSONException {
            String jsonString = readFile("prop.json"); //URL of your json file
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);     
            JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("value");
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArr.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject tempJsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(j);
                System.out.println(tempJsonObj.get("name"));
                System.out.println(tempJsonObj.get("kind"));
                System.out.println(tempJsonObj.get("url"));
            }
}
```

**Read JSON file:**

```
public String readFile(String filename) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: i am having too many parameters (100) to pass like that JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONJObject(.....);  . any alternative would you suggest

Comment: Please check the updated code. There is code to parse `JSON` from the file and convert to `String`. Hope this helps you.